# Is there no DatePicker for xaml in Windows 8 Metro?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

According to [this tutorial](http://debugmode.net/2012/01/03/working-with-datepicker-control-in-windows-8-html5-metro-app/), the DatePicker control is definitely present in the Javascript for Windows 8 Metro. So far I could not find it for the c#/xaml stack. Does anybody know if it is there and if not - if it will be available in the future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no built-in `DatePicker` usable from XAML in the Windows 8 Developer Preview.

Comment: That sucks. I don't want to vote this answer up, even thought it is correct. :-)

Comment: We need a Date and Time Picker for XAML/C#-based apps.

Comment: @Arrow:  If that is a suggestion, perhaps consider creating an entry on the [Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) (while this isn't a Visual Studio feature, it's the only way I know of to get feedback to the right people).

Comment: Oh thanks @JamesMcNellis, just found that there is already a suggestion over there. I up-voted it and added my comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2888664-add-date-time-picker-control-to-windows-8-metro-xa

Answer (score 2):

You can also inspect our [pack](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Product.aspx?lang=en&pid=150&tid=overview) of Windows 8 controls (I'm sorry for this ad, but it seems to be relevant to the question)

Answer (score 1):

Telerik however have controls, including a datepicker in their Windows 8 offering: http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro/controls/chart.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in datepicker for XAML, but there I found one here:

http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/19/example-metro-app-winrt-homemade-chart-and-datepicker-for-metro-apps/

that you can use if you cant afford Telerik ;)